# Linear Homogeneous Matrix Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

I was wondering whether the classical procedure of solving a system of linear homogeneous differential equations by finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors is applicable to Matrix-equations as well, meaning I am having the following problem:

Find a $2n\times n$ matrix $X$ such that

$
X'=AX$

where $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&-E \\ K & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $E=diag(1,..,1)$ denotes the identity matrix in dimension $n$ and $K$ is a symmetric positive semi-definite $n\times n$-matrix.

Since this is my first question here, please don't be harsh on any typos etc. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first step it is nice to reduce the problem to a problem with square matrices. Thus you can try to split $X$ into two $n\times n$ matrices and rewrite your problem. Then you can define the exponential of a matrix for square matrices which is the general solution for such problems.

Comment: So I would find myself with something like
$X_1' = -X_2$ and $X_2'=KX_1$?!

Comment: That is a good start ! then you have : $$X_1''+KX_1=O_n$$ and $$X_1'=-X_2$$ This looks like a harmonic oscillator.

Comment: Solutions for $X_1$ are in $Span(exp(iKt),exp(-iKt))$ if you denote $t$ your variable

Comment: So in general I would have $X_1=c_1 \exp{iKt}+c_2 \exp{-iKt}$ and could try to determine the constants with some initial / final condition, I guess $X_2$ is in $Span(i \exp{iKt}, - \exp{-iKt})$ then?

Comment: I think $X_1$ should be in $Span(exp(iK^{\frac{1}{2}}t),exp(-iK^{\frac{1}{2}}t))$ but thanks anyway!

Comment: Actually using matrix series you can define $cos$ and $sin$ for matrices which is probably better than complex exponentials. And Yes sorry you need a square root that is why you have the positivity of $K$